# Why the logic works with functions but not using Classes, Merge sort algorithm

Tags: arrays, function, class, sorting, mergesort

I implemented merge sort using functions and it worked as expected. However, when wrapped in a class, it is giving Time Limit Exceeded error. I believe it has to do with how underlying memory allocations happen for a class object, can someone help me understand in detail what's causing this?

```py
# 2 ------ Using Class
class Solution:
    def mergeSortedLists(self, nums, start, mid, end):

        l1 = nums[start: mid+1]
        l2 = nums[mid+1: end+1]

        i, j = 0, 0
        while i < len(l1) and j < len(l2):

            if l1[i] < l2[j]:
                nums[start] = l1[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                nums[start] = l2[j]
                j += 1

            start += 1

        if i < len(l1):
            nums[start:end + 1] = l1[i:]
        else:
            nums[start:end + 1] = l2[j:]

    def mergeSort(self, nums, start, end):

        while start < end:
            mid = (start + end) // 2
            self.mergeSort(nums, start, mid)
            self.mergeSort(nums, mid + 1, end)
            self.mergeSortedLists(nums, start, mid, end)

    def sortArray(self, nums):
        return self.mergeSort(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1)

a= Solution()
print(a.sortArray([7,6,4,3,2,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the class wrapper could not make this a correct sort.  The while loop in `mergeSort` makes no sense. `start` and `end` can never change.  You want:

```
    def mergeSort(self, nums, start, end):
        if start >= end:
            return
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        self.mergeSort(nums, start, mid)
        self.mergeSort(nums, mid + 1, end)
        self.mergeSortedLists(nums, start, mid, end)
```

Also the little test stub can only print `None`.   Here you want:

```
nums = [7,6,4,3,2,1]
Solution().sortArray(nums)
print(nums)
```